# in scala how to benefit from EmptyHouse in flatmap?

Tags: scala

I like the fact that flatmap automatically without any of my intervention skips 'Option' In an array of results I get.

However I also like to create for classes empty implementations like

'House'
'EmptyHouse'
'BeautifulHouse'

Is there a way to let flatmap know to ignore 'EmptyHouse' just as it would ignore 'Option'?   This without code repetion every time I call 'flatMap'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `flatMap` (or just `flatten`) on a collection of `Option` will indeed remove any occurence of `None`.
This is no magic, it is simply because `Option` can be treated as an `Iterable` (thanks to `Option.option2Iterable`) of zero (for `None`) or 1 (for `Some`)
elements.
Thus you could just do the same with your own classes:

```
class House
object EmptyHouse extends House
object BeautifulHouse extends House

implicit def houseToIterable( house: House ) = {
  if ( house == EmptyHouse ) Iterable.empty[House] else Iterable( house )
}
```

Mandatory repl test:

```
scala> val list = List( new House, EmptyHouse, BeautifulHouse )
list: List[House] = List(House@697af9a, EmptyHouse$@2fc9fc38, BeautifulHouse$@75cdd90a)
scala> list.flatten
res1: List[House] = List(House@697af9a, BeautifulHouse$@75cdd90a)
```

Now, I would not necessarily recommend this. Unless your class (unlike here with your `House` class) 
really represents some kind of collection, implicitly converting it to an `Iterable` really feels like an abuse. Especially when you can just as easily do:

```
list.filter( house != EmptyHouse )
```